# Rwanda: Tutsis passing themselves as Hutus during the genocide

Tags: africa, genocide, ethnicity, rwanda

I'm searching for info about one (minor) question concerning the genocide in Rwanda 1994: Is there evidence of Tutsis trying to pass themselves off as Hutus to avoid being killed?

(I know that this would have been hard if one was very large, but maybe a small Tutsi would have been able to pass himself off as a large Hutu?)

If there is such evidence, I would also like to ask whether those people actually succeeded.

---

EDIT:
As to the assumption that size played a role, I want to quote:

> "Those of you who live along the road, jump on the people
>   with long noses, who are tall and slim, and want to dominate us." (Peterson: "Me Against My Brother: at war in Somalia, Sudan, and Rwanda. A journalist reports from thebattlefields of Africa", 2000, p. 327).

Comment: There is an implicit assumption that size was relevant. That is not supported by the material I have read.

Comment: @ Mark: thanks for the edit and comment. I added a quote and reference to the note of body hight. However, I would like to know which other features were used for distinction. Would this be a "good" Stackexchange-question?

Comment: Apparantly, at least in parts the assumed ethnicity played little role " For example, one community in the northwest lost 5% of its population despite the fact that only a single Tutsi lived there." http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Rwandan_Genocide#Malthusian_element

Comment: @mart: thank you for the link -- I had never heard of rationalwiki before.

Comment: My understanding (This is not an area where I've done lots of research) is that the difference between a Hutu and Tutsi is like the difference between an Iowan and an Ohioan - obvious to those involved, but effectively indefinable for an external viewer.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Well, the Belgians tried to make it ethnic differences that can be seen by Europeans: The even issued ID cards: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_groups_in_Rwanda#Ethnic_identity_cards_in_contemporary_Rwanda (I hope it is in line with the standards of this forum to use wikipedia as a quick reference).

Comment: I prefer wikipedia references to unsupported assertions. I believe the page you reference hints at the notion that the ethnic divide was invented by the Belgians

Comment: my main point was not whether or not it was invented, altered or simply formalized by the Belgians (that would be another topic, I believe), but that at the point of the genocide, there was an official record of who was Tutsi and who was Hutu. In light of my original question, this would mean: Maybe forging an ID card would make it possible to pass as Hutu. However, the comments to my post show that in some cases (perceived) ethnic identity did not play any role. In this respect, it would not have helped to pass as Hutu in any way.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question, but I think a broader understanding on how the killers found their victims would be needed (and this is likely to vary in time and from place to place).

Comment: You have it reversed, the tall ones are the Tutsi. People know who is who. A Tutsi trying to pass himself off as a Hutu would not have a good chance of success. (Mark Wallace's comment above is correct.)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly I got reversed -- but it might be some misunderstanding as English is not my mother tongue. My example above was meant: A relatively small Tutsi (compared to otherwise large Tutsis) could maybe pass herself off as a relatively tall Hutu (compared to the otherwise smaller Hutus). Hutus were said to be smaller, Tutsis taller. So a Tutsi who is quite small (compared to other Tutsis) has better chances to be mistaken as Hutu than a Tutsi who's of "normal Tutsi hight". Did I somehow use wrong syntax above so that this did not become clear?

Comment: @mart: yes, I actually try to read a lot on the different approaches and explanations. And as your link above suggests, sometimes ethnicity was not important or just a convenient label. However, in the cases in which ethnicity did play a role it would still be interesting IMHO whether there were attempts to switch ethnic identity. However, as Mark Wallace and Tyler Durden say, distinction is maybe something that only members of either group can do -- also preventing any switches. I would still love to get pointed towards good sources in that respect. Have not found any so far...